# Duplicate Items In Specific Languages

Tags: performance-optimization

Is there an efficient way to copy a subtree of items but only keep language versions from the original items that a user chooses? Currently I have a process which duplicates items and then removes the unwanted language version but it is multiple steps. I use `Item.CopyTo(Item item, string name)` and then loop through the result removing language versions. Then I find what languages to remove and loop through the new items. For each language to remove I get the item in that language and use `myItem.Versions.RemoveAll(false)`.

Answer (score 4):

I would use PowerShell for this. The simplest way is to use a similar approach to what you're doing now (but in a few less steps):

Copy the item:

```
Copy-Item -Path $source.ItemPath -Destination $destination.ItemPath -Recursive
```

Them remove language versions:

```
Get-ChildItem $destination -Recurse | 
    Remove-ItemLanguage -Language "fr-CA"
```

However, you could make this a different way by only copying the language versions you want. I'm not sure how you'd do this in PowerShell off the top of my head - but you could do it with some code (you'd need to add some looping to traverse, add items and copy but hopefully this will give you the idea):

```
void Copy(Sitecore.Data.Items.Item sourceItem, Sitecore.Globalization.Language sourceLanguage,
        Sitecore.Data.Items.Item targetItem, Sitecore.Globalization.Language targetLanguage)
    {
        Sitecore.Data.Database masterDB = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");

        targetItem = masterDB.Items[targetItem.ID, targetLanguage];
        sourceItem = masterDB.Items[sourceItem.ID, sourceLanguage];

        if (targetItem == null || sourceItem == null || sourceItem.Versions.Count == 0)
            return;

        using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
        {
            try
            {
                if (targetItem.Versions.Count == 0)
                {
                    targetItem = targetItem.Versions.AddVersion();
                }
                targetItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
                sourceItem.Fields.ReadAll();
                foreach (Sitecore.Data.Fields.Field field in sourceItem.Fields)
                {
                    if (!field.Shared && !field.Name.StartsWith("__") && field.Name.Trim() != "")
                    {
                        targetItem.Fields[field.Name].SetValue(field.Value, true);
                    }
                }

                targetItem.Editing.EndEdit();
                targetItem.Editing.AcceptChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                targetItem.Editing.CancelEdit();
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }
```

(The above method [taken from here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210123025751/http://geekswithblogs.net/amaniar/archive/2010/10/25/copying-sitecore-items-across-languages.aspx))

Which of these is most efficient probably depends upon the sort of data you're copying (depth of the tree, number of languages, quantity of items etc).

If it's a process you need to do often as a developer I'd recommend PowerShell. If you need content editors to do it - I'd recommend wrapping it all in a tool (highly recommend Sitecore Sidekick for this).

Hope that helps you find the right solution!

Comment: Can you provide implementation details from the first link please. As is stands this is very close to a link only answer.

Comment: Sure, just out at the mo. I figured it wasn't necessary because it's just a standard part of powershell but I'll flesh it out this evening.

Comment: I read it wrong. I thought there were 2 options. Sorry.

Comment: I don't know if it fully answers the question though. Let me reassess and make it more clear later :-)

Comment: I updated my question to be clearer. I don't want to add language versions, I want to trim language version when copying a subtree of items. Let me know if I misunderstood this answer.

Comment: @OwenNiblock You can update your answer to both copy the tree and then call `Remove-ItemVersion`

Comment: I've updated off the top of my head / with Google so let me know if anything looks wonky. Happy to accept edits if you think of improvements :)